# Segmentation fault in a recursive approach to compute factorial(n)%m

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

I am trying to compute `n! % m` using recursion in `C`. This is the [code](http://ideone.com/g0C0h6) I am using

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define m 1000000007

long long int fact(long long int n) {
    if(n == 1)
        return (1);
    long long int n2 = (long long int)(fact(n-1));
    long long int k = (n*n2)%m;
    return k;
}

int main() {
    printf("%lld",fact(1000000));
}
```

This program gives `SEGMENTATION FAULT` , but if I replace the `fact` function with an iterative approach then program prints correct answer.The iterative `fact` function is

```
long long int fact(long long int n){
    long long int k =1;
    long long int i;
    for(i = n;i>1;i--)
        k = (k*i)%m;
    return k; 
}
```

So why the iterative approach works but the recursive approach is failing?

Comment: Looks like you are overflowing the call stack. Trying doing `ulimit -s unlimited` to increase the stack size.

Comment: The maximum height of your call stack is less than the maximum value of your `long long int i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your C compiler optimizes tail calls you can rewrite your recursive function to a tail recursive one:

```
long long int fact_aux(long long int n, long long int acc) {
    if(n <= 1)
        return acc;
    return fact_aux(n-1, (n * acc)%m);
}

long long int fact(long long int n) {
     return fact_aux(n, 1);
}
```

Note that the C standard doesn't require TCO so you have no guarantee this will be as effective as a loop. [GCC does it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/490324/1565698).

Answer (score 4):

try gdb, but likely its because you are reaching your max recursion depth, in other words running out of "memory" either literally or based on current rule sets for your os.