# Does static variables cause problem when there is too much calls of the function?

Tags: c

i'm trying to make a function that draws a square, but i want to do it recursively, so i'm using a static variable, one problem: my function seg faults when I pass too high parameters to it, so i'm asking you if that is because of the static, or something else, thanks for your help, here's the code:

```
int     square(int x, int y)
{
    static t_coord  pos;

    if (x < 0 || y < 0)
    {
        ft_puts(2, "Error"); // if the size is negative it displays error on stderr
        return (FAILURE);
    }
    if (!pos.y)
        pos.y++;
    if (pos.x == x)
    {
        if (pos.y == y)
            return (SUCCESS);
        pos.y++;
        pos.x = 1;
        write(1, "\n", 1);
    }
    else
        pos.x++;
    ft_write_case(pos.x, pos.y, x, y); // function to write either corner side or space (middle)
    return(square(x, y));
}
```

the problem doesnt come from my ft_write_case function because i replaced it by a simple write(1, "o", 1) and it did the same segmentation fault, thanks for the help

Comment: It's not the `static` variable. There's only one copy of the `static` variable. You're overflowing the stack with the `x` and `y` variables, and other behind-the-scenes stack usage.

Comment: When you call a function recursively, the recursive call should get you closer to the base case. You recurse with the same values of `x` and `y`, so it never stops recursing and you get a stack overflow.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3514283/509868)

Comment: @Barmar Although the `x` and `y` values don't change between calls, the `pos.x` and `pos.y` values do, so that should end the recursion.

Comment: Missed that return statement.

Comment: Note that the function will only work the first time it's called, since `pos.x` and `pos.y` will stay at their final values, and there's no way to reset them.

Comment: There's a limit on the size of the stack, it might take too many recursions before `pos.x` and `pos.y` reach `x` and `y`.

Comment: @user3386109 has a point. It would be better to pass `pos` as an argument, so you can call it with an initial value the first time.

Comment: "_ i want to do it recursively, so i'm using a static variable,_" is a non-sequitur, one does not follow from the other.  Recursion is generally ill-advised, and in this case probably not at all appropriate.

Comment: @Clifford, Re, "recursion is generally ill-advised," That depends on what language you're using. In some programming languages, recursion (especially [_tail_ recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)) is the _preferred_ way to express a computation.

Comment: ok so that means i'm overflowing the stack of my recursion? so if it's that even if I pass pos through arguments there will be as much recursions as there is now so this will not fix the issue

Comment: @SolomonSlow : I am not sure I agree, but this question is specifically about C code.  There are certainly cases where recursion offers a simple and elegant solution, but you have to guarantee convergence in a deterministic number of recursions within the resource constraints of the environment.  And you have to know what you are doing - which seems to be lacking here.

Comment: So I added pos.x = 0 and pos.y = 0 before return(SUCCESS) for the multiple time call and i still have this seg fault issue

Comment: @Clifford yes in fact I just want to make the function as shorter as possible si i want to use recursion for that

Comment: @Fayeure What's the largest size that works?

Comment: @user3386109 since it has 2 values its hard to tell but I tested it for x = 100 and y = 100 and it worked, then x = 1000 and y = 1000 which did segmentation fault

Comment: The code already seems longer then necessary even for a non-recursive solution - I don't see how recursion is helping you here.

Comment: @Clifford its just for optimisation: i'm trying to get the fastest way with less operations

Comment: For 1000x1000 the recursion depth is 1000000 and each recursion might use perhaps 16 bytes of stack on a 64bit system (the two int parameters, and the return address).  So about 16Mb - that is more stack that the default process stack for Linux or Windows for example.

Comment: It is not am optimisation in terms of memory use and how much faster is it?  Have you measured it?  All that memory has to get pushed and popped, I doubt it is any kind of optimisation.