# How this recursive function works in langage C?

Tags: c

I'm using online debugger to try to understand, how it works but it is not clear.

https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int plus(unsigned int x, unsigned int y){
  return x+y;
}

unsigned int schema (unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int a, unsigned int (*f)(unsigned int, unsigned int)){
    return((y==0)?a:(*f)(schema(x,y-1,a,f),x));
}

unsigned int prod(unsigned int x, unsigned int y){
    return(schema(x,y,0,plus));
}

int main()
{
    int m,n;
    
    printf("Donner deux nombres ? : ");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    printf("%d * %d = %d\n", m, n, prod(m,n));

    return 0;
}
```

How does the **schema** function to calls **plus** function with the correct parameters ?

The code is here : https://onlinegdb.com/nAglj8NwZr

Here the debug :

```
Reading symbols from a.out...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/a.out 
Donner deux nombres ? : 3 2

Breakpoint 2, prod (x=21845, y=1431655088) at main.c:20
20      unsigned int prod(unsigned int x, unsigned int y){
(gdb) step

Breakpoint 1, prod (x=3, y=2) at main.c:21
21          return(schema(x,y,0,plus));
(gdb) step

Breakpoint 4, schema (x=32767, y=4294962119, a=0, f=0xf0b5ff) at main.c:16
16      unsigned int schema (unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int a, unsigned int (*f)(unsigned int, unsigned int)){
(gdb) step

Breakpoint 3, schema (x=3, y=2, a=0, f=0x555555555189 <plus>) at main.c:17
17          return((y==0)?a:(*f)(schema(x,y-1,a,f),x));
(gdb) step

Breakpoint 4, schema (x=0, y=0, a=0, f=0x0) at main.c:16
16      unsigned int schema (unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int a, unsigned int (*f)(unsigned int, unsigned int)){
(gdb) step

Breakpoint 3, schema (x=3, y=1, a=0, f=0x555555555189 <plus>) at main.c:17
17          return((y==0)?a:(*f)(schema(x,y-1,a,f),x));
(gdb) step

Breakpoint 4, schema (x=0, y=24, a=0, f=0x0) at main.c:16
16      unsigned int schema (unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int a, unsigned int (*f)(unsigned int, unsigned int)){
(gdb) step

Breakpoint 3, schema (x=3, y=0, a=0, f=0x555555555189 <plus>) at main.c:17
17          return((y==0)?a:(*f)(schema(x,y-1,a,f),x));
(gdb) step
18      }
(gdb) step

Breakpoint 6, plus (x=3, y=0) at main.c:12
12      unsigned int plus(unsigned int x, unsigned int y){
(gdb) step

Breakpoint 5, plus (x=0, y=3) at main.c:13
13          return x+y;
(gdb) step
14      }
(gdb) step
schema (x=3, y=1, a=0, f=0x555555555189 <plus>) at main.c:18
18      }
(gdb) step

Breakpoint 6, plus (x=3, y=1) at main.c:12
12      unsigned int plus(unsigned int x, unsigned int y){
(gdb) step

Breakpoint 5, plus (x=3, y=3) at main.c:13
13          return x+y;
(gdb) step
14      }
(gdb) step
schema (x=3, y=2, a=0, f=0x555555555189 <plus>) at main.c:18
18      }
(gdb) step
prod (x=3, y=2) at main.c:22
22      }
(gdb) step
__printf (format=0x555555556023 "%d * %d = %d\n") at printf.c:28
28      printf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
3 * 2 = 6
[Inferior 1 (process 2233) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Thanks a lot if someboby could explain this code.

Comment: I would recommend rewriting the body of `schema` into an `if` + `else` section, that makes it a lot easier to read. Other than that my only guess at your confusion would be the function pointer syntax?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to make your question more specific. It [is not possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797) to explain how a bunch of code works in this format, because we have no way to know *why* you don't understand it already, *what* you don't understand about it, or *how* to express things in a way that would be clearer to you.

Comment: The `schema()` function recurses `n` times, and on the way back adds `m` to result each time it returns to the previous instance. The `a` is a bit of a red herring. it serves no role and at the top of the recursion the code might as well use `0` directly.

Comment: `return((y==0)?a:(*f)(schema(x,y-1,a,f),x));` is a lot easier to read when formatted nicely, and if we get rid of the extraneous parens.  `return y == 0 ? a : f(schema(x, y-1, a, f), x);`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, yes sorry, I will try to be more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider providing `4` and `5` to your program. Perhaps this will help you to visualize the recursion.

```
prod(4, 5)
schema(4, 5, 0, plus)
plus(schema(4, 5-1, 0, plus), 4)
plus(plus(schema(4, 4-1, 0, plus), 4), 4)
plus(plus(plus(schema(4, 3-1, 0, plus), 4), 4), 4)
plus(plus(plus(plus(schema(4, 2-1, 0, plus), 4), 4), 4), 4)
plus(plus(plus(plus(plus(schema(4, 1-1, 0, plus), 4), 4), 4), 4), 4)
plus(plus(plus(plus(plus(0, 4), 4), 4), 4), 4)
plus(plus(plus(plus(4, 4), 4), 4), 4)
plus(plus(plus(8, 4), 4), 4)
plus(plus(12, 4), 4)
plus(16, 4)
20
```

Note that because `prod` only calls another function, [tail-call optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514283/c-tail-call-optimization) may take place. However, `schema` calls itself, and then feed the result to the function pointer provided, so those stack frames have to remain, meaning TCO cannot be performed.

If, however, you were dealing with a sightly smarter `schema` function, which used that `a` parameter usefully as an updating accumulator, TCO would be possible.

```
unsigned int schema(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int a, 
                    unsigned int (*f)(unsigned int, unsigned int)) {
    if (y == 0) return a;

    return schema(x, y-1, f(x, a), f);
}
```

Comment: I think the code is not optimize because it just only for an example how pointer function works. I found this code in the book, it is not mine.