# calling main() in main() in c

Tags: c

Is it possible to call `main()` within the `main()` function in c?

Comment: Did you try it?  Did it work?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from calling a function within its context. It's called recursion.

Comment: @Donnie just because something would appear to work in a test example doesn't mean it always will, or is correct. "try it and see if it works" is often dangerous in C.

Comment: @nos: I still would have liked to see the author cared to at least try first and share his/her experiences before asking the question. I don't fancy people using this as an interactive Google interface.

Comment: It's a legitimate question, e.g. the C++ standard specifically disallows it, while a "try and see if it works" approach would likely shown that "it works" if this question was about C++, yet it would not be correct.

Comment: "Did you try it?" has little to do with the question. There are plenty of things ridiculous compiler implementations allow (like `void *x; x+=42;`) which are not legal C. This, however (recursive calling of `main`) is legal C.

Comment: @nos: Unless your version of C++ happens to call global constructors from an invisible first-statement in `main`, and then ends up calling them every time you recurse into `main`... ;-)

Comment: If you want examples of `main()` calling `main()`, here are plenty: http://www.ioccc.org/ It's the website of the International Obfuscated C Code Contest, and folding everything into a single function called `main` is an effective obfuscation technique.

Comment: @cmaster many of the IOCCC entries don't comply with the ISO C standard

Comment: @M.M That's true. But they do make for *interesting* examples ;-)

Comment: This can also be used for code-golfing.

Comment: My winning entry in the 17th IOCCC recursively called main(), a program which graphed polynomials.  Mine most certainly did comply with the C99 standard: https://www.ioccc.org/years.html#2004_hoyle

Answer (score 43):

Yes, C allows you to call your main function (while C++ [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532912/call-main-itself-in-c) )

Comment: I'm curious, why can't you call it in C++?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: The simplest implementation of global constructors (without special support from the OS and underlying C runtime entry code) is for the C++ compiler to generate a function call at the beginning of `main` (`__main` is a common name for it) which calls all the global constructors. Having global objects be reconstructed every time `main` gets called recursively would be a rather bad thing... :-)

Comment: @nos Could you point to a place in any C standard that specifically addresses `main()` recursion, if it is specifically addressed?

Comment: I think you should link [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128321/can-main-function-call-itself-in-c) instead.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Simply because the standard says you cannot ;)

Answer (score 23):

It is indeed allowable to call `main()` from itself, even avoiding stack overflow with the same method used for any other recursive code, a terminating condition such as with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf ("Running main with argc = %d, last = '%s'\n",
        argc, argv[argc-1]);
    if (argc > 1)
        return main(argc - 1, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

which, when run as `testprog 1 2 3`, outputs:

```
Running main with argc = 4, last = '3'
Running main with argc = 3, last = '2'
Running main with argc = 2, last = '1'
Running main with argc = 1, last = 'testprog'
```

However, since that's only *anecdotal* evidence, we should turn to the standard. ISO C11 section `4 Conformance` states:

> 1/ In this International Standard, "shall" is to be interpreted as a requirement on an implementation or on a program; conversely, "shall not" is to be interpreted as a prohibition.
>
> 2/ If a "shall" or "shall not" requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined. Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International Standard by the words "undefined behavior" or by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior. There is no difference in emphasis among these three; they all describe "behavior that is undefined".
>
> 3/ A program that is correct in all other aspects, operating on correct data, containing unspecified behavior shall be a correct program and act in accordance with 5.1.2.3.

Now, since there's no explicit *prohibition* anywhere in the standard on `main()` calling itself, clause 3 above is the controlling aspect.

Further support can be seen in two places (my bold), first in section `5.1.2.2.3 Program termination`:

> 1/ If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a return from the ***initial*** call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument;

And then in section `7.21.3 Files`:

> 5/ The file may be subsequently reopened, by the same or another program execution, and its contents reclaimed or modified (if it can be repositioned at its start). If the `main` function returns to its ***original*** caller, or if the `exit` function is called, all open files are closed (hence all output streams are flushed) before program termination.

Both these sub-sections support the possibility that there may be *other* calls to `main()` over and above the initial/original one.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, we can call the main() within the main() function.

The process of calling a function by the function itself is known as Recursion.

Well,you can call a main() within the main() function ,but you should have a condition that does not call the main() function to terminate the program.

Otherwise,the program will never return and run infinitely.

Comment: It will cause a stack overflow when the stack space is used up.

Comment: Except when the compiler does tail call optimization, but anyway you can't rely on that so endless recursion is to be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

*Yes you can*.
**Simple Program:**

```
int main()
{
    printf("Anything");
    main();
    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation:**

A `call stack` or `function stack` is used for several related purposes, but the main reason for having one is to keep track of the point to which each active subroutine should return control when it finishes executing.

A `stack overflow` occurs when too much memory is used on the call stack.

Here function `main()` is called repeatedly and its return address is stored in the stack. After stack memory is full. It shows `stack overflow error`.