# Calling main function more than once is a good practice in C?

Tags: c

I saw a C code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main  ()
{
    static int ivar = 5;
    printf ("%d", ivar--);

    if (ivar)
        main ();
}
```

which outputs :

```
54321
```

I'm a novice in C and I guess until the condition fails the `main`  method is called again and again. Since I'm a novice in C, is it good practice to call the `main` function more than once as in the above case? Are there any real world cases, where this kind of code is very useful?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You retagged 22 seconds ahead of me.

Comment: Arrgh, `void main`. C is not C++, C++ is not C. If you saw *some* C code ("code" is not a countable word), why did you tag this C++?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes : Sorry, people have retagged it

Comment: one question - why would you wish to do this?

Comment: @EdHeal : no as a novice in C, i just want to know it is good or bad to use `main` twice.. thats my question..

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling main() in main() in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238179/calling-main-in-main-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A while-loop would be more suitable. Recursion makes sense when, with each recursion, you are doing a *different* job -- typically a smaller one.

What this code is *really* doing is demonstrating function-local static variables: the `ivar` is only initialised in the *first* call of `main`. Each time you recurse, it is decremented despite the `ivar=5` statement.

`main` has a special meaning. Idiomatically, it should **initialise the environment** and then call some other function which drives the application logic.

An optimising compiler might well transform that code into an iterative version anyway.

Answer (score 9):

In your example, it doesn't matter because it's a very small piece of code. But in the general case I think calling `main` is a bad idea for the following reasons:

- **Readability.** When examining a program no one would assume that `main` will be called at one point. When you see that it is, you have to back track and reread the whole thing. Besides, `main` is not a meaningful name in the sense that it's not clear what the intent of the recursion is. So I'd write another function with a meaningful name to reflect this.
- **Reusability.** It's quite probable that a new function with a meaningful name will be useful in more than one place in a complex program.
- **Command line arguments.** At one point you may need command line arguments in your program. Even GUI programs need them (for file associations etc.). And you will need to refactor all your calls to main to take that into account.
- **C++ compatibility.** It's illegal in C++.

Comment: Yay! Finally someone actually gives reasons.

Answer (score 7):

I would say it's rarely, if ever, a good idea to call the `main` function.  If you're going to recurse, create a function to do it.

Comment: Okay.  But why would you say that?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley `main` isn't just any old function, it's special and has a well-defined purpose: to start the program, not to be an explicit part of it.  I could imagine a compiler that doesn't even process it as an independent 'function', making it impossible to call.

Answer (score 3):

This is not often seen (I've never seen it done before), very confusing, since main is supposed to be called once when the program starts and end when the program ends, and largely impractical in most real programs, since you would need to stop the subsequent calls to main() from parsing the command line again.

It's far more reasonable to just write a separate recursive function and call it from main and using ordinary function arguments instead of static variables.

Answer (score 1):

It's called **recursion** and it can be very useful.  For instance traversing a tree.  Some math calculations also use recursion.

Comment: Recursion is quite useful, but (I'd argue at least) not with the main method.

Comment: That was my initial feeling too.  But after thinking about it...why not?  Main is just another function.

Comment: `main` isn't just another function, it has a special meaning and purpose, to start the program running.

Comment: Right, the operating system calls it.  But after that, it's just another function.  Isn't it?  :)

Comment: Nitpick: The OS might not call `main` directly -- in Windows, it generally calls some code in the runtime library (which turns command-line args into `argv`, among other things), that *then* calls `main`.

Comment: Sure, but after the program is running, it's just another function...right?

Comment: @SteveWellens From the compiler's perspective it's just another function. From the programmer's perspective, it is a special function with a not-very-descriptive name. To me, all the name `main` conveys is that the program starts here. If you were trying to do something else with it, its name would be a lie in my book.