# Calling Main Method from Main Method

Tags: java

This is my first question in this forum. 
Hope to have a good experience!

My question is related to Java. In C/C++, sometimes we need to call `main()` function while being in `main()` function itself. Can the same thing be done in Java also?

If yes, suggest me some way to do it and also to terminate the program from the second `main()` call.

i.e.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
     main();//The question is about this part and also how to get out from this call directly to termination 
}
```

One more thing. I am new to JAVA, so please be as descriptive as you can be. 
Thanks for your support in Advance!

Comment: While it's possible, it's probably not necessary. What are you trying to achieve with a recursive call to main()?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would ever want to do this in _any_ language.

Comment: Sounds to me like a bad idea.

Answer (score 6):

Well it *can* be done, but you really shouldn't do this ever (in C or C++ either).

All you have to do is call `main` with an array of `String`s.  You could pass in the array as it was initially passed in, or you could generate your own array.

To exit from the recursive call to `main`, you would call `System.exit()` passing in some error code.

Again, I want to emphasize that you should probably *never ever* do this in any programming language. You claim that you sometimes need to do this in C/C++ but that is not true. You really shouldn't do it.

Comment: Thank You @Daniel. 
But I'd really like to know why it is not suggested.

Comment: @Neferseti Well first of all, calling main is illegal in C++. The main problem with calling `main` recursively is that it goes against people's expectations. `main` is the entry point to the program, and nothing more. Nobody reading your code would expect `main` to be called any time besides the entry to your code. In any case, the use for recursion is to do a different task from what you are currently doing. If you're just trying to restart your program, that's not a good use for recursion. Just use a loop. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7811155/864027) for more details.