# understanding static int execution

Tags: c, recursion, static

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    static int i = 5;

    if(--i){
        main();
        printf("%d,", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm unable to find why the value of `i` is becoming 0 every time.

Comment: Recursive `main()`.... I don't like _weird_ things.. :)

Comment: It becomes zero because you decrease it? Is the problem perhaps your understanding about how `static` local variables work? Maybe is a problem understanding recursion? To better understand the recursion you should learn how to use a debugger and how to step over code line by line, and more importantly step *into* function calls. Do that and it will become clear.

Comment: Switch the 2 lines in the if and see what happens

Comment: Write out the code line-by-line, replacing `main` with the code that will actually get executed, so you end up with 1 procedural function. It'll make sense

Comment: I tried @Johnny Mopp it is giving output as 4, 3, 2, 1

Comment: There is little point having a `static int` in `main` unless it recurses, which is *unwise behaviour*.

Comment: Correct. You do understand that static variables only get initialized once? They are kind of like global variables in lifetime but only have local scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [recursive call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) to `main()` in your code, till `if(--i)` is not down to 0. The print statement does not get a chance to execute.

Once `i` becomes zero, the control returns, and the value of `i`, is, well, 0, then.

*[I don't have a photo editor handy right now, sorry]*,

Try to have a look at the rough graphics to get an idea.

[image]

FWIW, `i` is having `static` storage, so it *holds* the value *across* function calls.

<sup>(*I assumed the last part is already understood, just adding for sake of clarity.*)</sup>

Comment: I like this one, also a link to the post calling main to main http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238179/calling-main-in-main-in-c

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation @Sourav Ghosh

Comment: @sabhithavangaveti welcome. BTW, [you can consider accepting an answer that helped you.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062)

Answer (score 3):

here's your program's execution and values:

```
i = 5; --i; main ()// i==4
i = 4; --i; main ()// i==3
i = 3; --i; main ()// i==2
i = 2; --i; main ()// i==1
i = 1; --i; // i == 0 ,main is not called!
```

and only then the program comes back from recursion:

```
printf("%d,", i);
```