# Why does "printf" not produce any output?

Tags: c, printf

I am learning to program in `C`. Could you explain why nothing is printed here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char a[]="abcde";
    printf ("%s", a);
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

On many systems `printf` is buffered, i.e. when you call `printf` the output is placed in a buffer instead of being printed immediately. The buffer will be flushed (aka the output printed) when you print a newline `\n`.

On all systems, your program will print despite the missing `\n` as the buffer is flushed when your program ends.

Typically you would still add the `\n` like:

```
printf ("%s\n", a);
```

An alternative way to get the output immediately is to call `fflush` to flush the buffer. From the man page:

> For output streams, fflush() forces a write of all user-space
> buffered data for the given output or update stream via the stream's
> underlying write function.

Source: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @Barmar and quoted by @Alter Mann it is required that the buffer is flushed when the program ends.

Quote from @Alter Mann:

> If the main function returns to its original caller, or if the exit function is called, all open files are closed (hence all output streams are flushed) before program termination.

See [calling main() in main() in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238179/calling-main-in-main-in-c/32062695#32062695)

Comment: C systems are **required** to flush output when the program ends.

Comment: @Barmar, good point: _If the main function returns to its original caller, or if the exit function is called, all open files are closed (hence all output streams are flushed) before program termination._ But in this case there is no call to `exit()` nor `return`, could this be what's causing the problem?

Comment: @AlterMann Running off the end of the function causes it to return to its caller.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, `return` is optional, very strange!

Comment: I got that from the question **you** linked to in a comment above.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code, I find this answer very misleading...

Comment: There is also C11 7.21.2/2 "Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined"

Comment: @DavidRanieri: Note that C99 follows C++98 in that falling off the end of `main()` is equivalent to executing `return 0;`.  I don't like that; I regard it as a misfeature.  However, it is standard C for the whole of the current millennium, so the program shown has a valid exit status unless compiled for C90.

Comment: There's nothing misleading about this answer. The user had a simple problem and the answer provides a simple way to solve the problem. The explanation is also very helpful and relevant. The code is defective in that the user doesn't get the output they were looking for.

Comment: @FontFamily But... they do. They must. As has already been explained.

Answer (score 3):

Strangely enough, it seems that nobody posted the adjusted code where the buffer is flushed yet...:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char a[]="abcde";
    printf ("%s", a);
    fflush(stdout);
    //On some systems the line above will fail, in that case use: fflush(NULL);
}
```

*Also note that this code probably doesn't do what you **actually** want to do.
What I assume you really want to do is:*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char a[]="abcde";
    printf ("%s\n", a);
   //The '\n' makes sure the next thing you print will be on the following line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, I can make a couple of points about this without
making it confusing.
Printf is not the thing being buffered, it's stdio, so
all similar functions will behave in the same way.
To demonstrate the buffering, all you have to do is
printf a lot of characters, usually more than 1024,
and printf will print as you will have exceeded the
maximum buffer length and it will automatically fflush.
All the other points are, of course, also correct and valid.