# in c system() executes before printf() even when printf come first

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I just started using the system() function in c, and I thought of starting the same executable from within it self using the system function, so I wrote the following program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("some string");
    system("./a.out");
}
```

-I used gcc to compile it-

when I ran the program it did not print anything, it just kept going until I used the shortcut ctrl-c to stop the execution,then it started printing the output(it did not print anything until I stopped it)

I believe the statements should execute sequentially, why did it not print anything until I stopped it?

Comment: `system` is using `fork` under the hood. And the output of `printf` is buffered and can get flushed at any moment - before or after executing the child. Flush it explicitly by adding `\n` or usng `fflush(stdout)` if the order is important..

Comment: The output stream is buffered, so the text you print may not appear until you flush the stream or the process exits.

Comment: ty for the explanation.

Comment: [printf anomaly after "fork()"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2530663/995714), [why does "printf" not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39180642/995714)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, when `stdout`is connected to a terminal, it is line-buffered.

```
printf("some string");
```

doesn't have a `'\n'` in it and you aren't calling `fflush(stdout);` after it either, so all this `printf("some string");` does is copy `"some string"` into your `stdout`'s output buffer.

The buffer is flushed as the end of `main`.

`printf("some string\n");` would flush the buffer immediately, provided `stdout` is connected to a terminal and you didn't change `stdout`'s buffering.

`printf("some string"); fflush(stdout);` will flush the buffer immediately regardless of context and without the need for the `'\n'`.

Comment: I think it is important to explain why the output reordering it is happening with `system` but not with some other functions.