# C program recursive call to main() with and without parameters

Tags: c, recursion, program-entry-point

Why does it give an error of segmentation fault(core dumped) and gives no output in 1st case ?Can anyone explain how program is program callls main recursively with parameters?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int i = 2;
    if (i<7)
    {
        main();
        printf("%d ", i);
        i++;
        //main(10);
    }
}
```

-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int i = 5;
    if (--i)
    {
     //main();
     printf("%d ", i);
     main(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: How many times do you expect `main` to get called in each case?

Comment: you never get to `i++` in the first case

Comment: 6 in first case and 4 times in second case @DavidSchwartz

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I'd love to hear your explanation for why `main` is called 6 times in the first case, given that the value of `i` never changes.

Comment: Why do you play such games with `main`. Your problem has nothing to do with the name of the function or the fact that `main` is special. You just have difficulties to understand how recursion works.

Comment: Never call main recursively. It is not a clever thing to do.

Comment: @Aconcagua This is wrong, what is your reference ? This is mine https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238188/7076153.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it doesn't get called 6 times. it's in the question, "it give an error of segmentation fault(core dumped) and gives no output in 1st case"

Comment: @Stargateur You seem to be right, couldn't find it in the C standard either. Mixed it up with C++ (6.6.1.3: "The function main shall not be used within a program.")...

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `main()` first and then incrementing `i`

```
 if (i<7)
    {
        main();           // <-- main called when i still 2
        printf("%d ", i);
        i++;              // <-- statement never reached
        //main(10);
    }
```

Hence, while `main()` calls `main()` recursively, the statement `i++` is never reached.

You should increment `i` before calling `main()`

```
if (i<7)
    {
        i++;
        main();
        printf("%d ", i);
        //main(10);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** ***StackOverflow*** (*Pun or no pun, it's true both ways*).

**First:** *Some important information*

This case has nothing to do with passing an argument to `main()` or not. Actually, as per the latest C standard, `C11`, for a hosted environment, the conforming signature of `main()` is `int main(void)` and following that, `main(10);` is wrong, altogether.

---

Now, coming to the actual problem here,

- In the first case, change of `i` value happens *after* the call to `main()`, so in effect, the value of `i` never get changed because the control never reaches the statement which modifies `i`. Hence, it's an infinite loop, and because of the recursive call to `main()`, stack overflow happens.
- In later case, `i` value gets updated before call to `main()`, so that value actually reflects. Thus, at some point (after 4 occurrences, actually), the `if` condition meets a FALSE condition and the recursive call ends and the *stack* unwinds.

Comment: @ash Well, that is explained in the answer. You can just call `main()` in the second call also, will not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

1st case the i++ after the call of main(), that means the program has no chance to add the i, and into infinity loop, and stackoverflow! haha....

but the 2nd case, it's reduce the i before you call the main.

Answer (score 1):

First case:

`i++` is positionned after the call to `main`. So `i` will always be equal to 2, as you never reach this part of the code. You are then calling your `main` function everytime, leading to an infinite recursion, and thus to the segmentation fault. The fix for this case would be to increase i before calling the main function.

```
if (i<7)
{
    i++; // Increment before calling the main function, so i value is changed
    main();
    printf("%d ", i);
}
```

Do note that it will lead to something which looks like your second case, except that you will print several "7".

Seconde case:

In the second case, you are decreasing the value of `i` everytime you enter your if condition. When you finally can't enter your if condition anymore, it means `i` is equal to 0 (as `if(0)` is equivalent to `if(false)`). Everytime you will return to the previous called main function, `i` will still be equal to 0, explaining why you are displaying "0" everytime. If you want to print the different values, you can place your `printf` before the call to the main function for instance.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case:

"i" is never incremented therefore you run in an infinite loop and get an overflow.

In the second case:

You call the recursion before displaying the value of "i", after four calls "i" equals to 0 and your recursion stack unwinds.

Modify your condition and perform outputs before the recursion call.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, i is never incremented, hence, the main keeps getting called and soon enough there is no more stack memory available to the program.

In the second case, the last updated value of i is intact throughout the lifetime of i. As i is static, program is referring to the same  memory address on all the iterations. While printing i you see the last updated value, that is 0, as output.