# If i use else, "EVEN NUMBER ENTERED" is printed once, if i dont it is printed TWICE. Why?

Tags: c, stack, output

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter a EVEN Number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    if (num%2!=0)
    {
        printf("WRONG INPUT\n\n");
        main();
    }

    printf("EVEN NUMBER ENTERED\n");
}
```

[image: Here Is The Output For Above Code When I DONT USE ELSE]

Is it something to do with how A C Program stores information using stack? Or am i missing some concept

Comment: consider a loop rather than recursively calling `main`

Comment: i know the method using a loop but i wanted to get my basics with recursion clear as i have started programming recently

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text, show the text itself.

Comment: If that is the result of getting your basics of recursion clear, then you should review them from start.

Comment: If you make N mistakes before entering an even number, you will get N+1 message that an even number was entered.  Don't use recursion on `main()` like that.  Yes, it is allowed in C (it isn't in C++ — yet another of the differences between the languages), but it isn't a good idea.  Use a loop instead.

Comment: Where is the `else` you mention in the title. You do not have any `else` part in that code. If you compare things you should show us both.

Answer (score 0):

When you gave `3` as input, the `if` condition is true and `main()` will be called a 2nd time.

Then you gave an even number as input in which case, the flow of control won't enter the body of `if` and just print the "EVEN NUMBER ENTERED" message and the program control exits the 2nd `main()`.

Now the control goes back to the place where the `main()` was recursively called and executes what is left of the first `main()` call which happens to be the same "EVEN NUMBER ENTERED" message.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238179/calling-main-in-main-in-c) about making `main()` recursive. A recursive `main()` is not considered good.

Consider making another function and then calling it from `main()` like

```
int fn()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter an EVEN Number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    if (num%2!=0)
    {
        printf("WRONG INPUT\n\n");
        return fn();
    }
    printf("EVEN NUMBER ENTERED\n");
}
```

Or use `else` as you did first.