# Why would you recursively call main?

Tags: c

I read in C you can recursively call main, but why would you do it?

Comment: Short answer - There isn't a good reason to do it, and it is almost always a bad idea. It just isn't forbidden.

Comment: To demonstrate weird C tricks to your students. No other reason.

Comment: "Because it's there!" - George Leigh Mallory

Comment: Seen once in actual production code: `signal(SIGINT, main);`.  Not kidding - it still blows my mind.

Comment: You could call `main` if `main` performs the function you want to perform at some point in your program. This happens only rarely because `main` is the routine that runs your overall program, and you rarely want to perform the same general function as your overall program as a subtask of your program. It simply does not arise naturally very often. It is not inherently bad design.

Comment: If you head over to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com you'll find lots of "good" reasons to do it...

Comment: @Lundin: "Ah, but a man's reach should exceed his grasp, or what's a heaven for?" - Robert Browning. See also "Hey, y'all - watch THIS..!"...

Comment: Anyways - `longjmp` back to the head of main would be "better". Why? Oh...no reason... :-)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good reason to do it, and it is almost always a bad idea. It just isn't forbidden.

Everything that can be done by calling main recursively can also be done some other, less obscure way, for example by defining a well-named function that is called immediately after entering `main` and calling that function recursively.

It is allowed in C because it was not explicitly forbidden - as main is just a function, that would require an explicit rule. On the contrary, some additional support for it has been added in the standard over the years, as discussed in answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238179/calling-main-in-main-in-c). Adding such a rule forbidding it now would be a breaking change and is therefore hardly feasible in practice, and arguably also a waste of effort, as this is rarely a problem.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I wouldn't say it is a "bad" idea. It's more like a weird idea. `main` is just a normal function like everything else. For example, a program that prints the arguments given in reverse:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
   if( argc <= 1 ) return 0;
   printf( "%s\n", argv[argc - 1] );
   return main( argc - 1, argv );
}
```

That being said, more recent C++ standards state that calling `main` is forbidden. This isn't C++, but that should still be held relevant.

Why should it be forbidden? There could be a number of reasons, despite common compiler implementations not caring about that rule and it working anyway. What speculation comes to mind for me is that that `main` can actually be implemented as a special entry point, some kind of jump in the assembly that will mangle your stack if you try and call it again. Basically, not a good idea, at least for future-proof code.

While examples for this behavior may be pretty much limited to small academic curiosities, I would pose a certain maintenance issue as the primary reason to avoid it:

- It isn't recommended,
- it is forbidden in a closely related standard, and
- that means it might not work in the future.

Comment: For C++, I think that in some implementations, the compiler may add code to `main` to call global constructors, so that it doesn't need help from the system startup code to make sure they execute.  If `main` can be called recursively then it needs to make sure that the constructors aren't executed on the subsequent calls.  This is probably as simple as setting a flag, but if recursive calls to `main` are totally forbidden, then the compiler's job becomes a little easier.

Comment: I think that's a good example too, @NateEldredge. More constraints = easier implementation.