# How to call main() from other functions in C

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I was going through the difference in C and C++ and I found a tricky point. Can you please elaborate the below points:

1. In C, we can call `main()` Function through other Functions.
2. In C++, we cannot call `main()` Function through other functions.

How to call `main()` from another function and what is the use case of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call main() itself in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532912/call-main-itself-in-c)

Comment: You can, but it isn't good practice. If you ever feel like you'd want to, then create another function with the same signature and call it instead.

Comment: how? just write `main()` or `main(argc, argv)`. There's no difference from other functions

Comment: There is no real world use case for calling `main` from another function AFAIK.

Comment: The use cases, IMHO, are: 1. a very bad way to run a loop while bombarding the stack in an attempt to bring a machine to it's knees... 2. terrible recursive argument parsing... There's a reason C++ thought it should protect itself from people who can't write a `while` loop...

Comment: The macOS java executable (yes, *that* executable) calls `JLI_Launch` which eventually re-executes the java `main`. It is not, I repeat *not*, pretty.

Answer (score 1):

@TrevorHickey hit the nail on the head (where did his answer go?) - C++ forbids calling `main` from within a different function (for good reason)... Not that any compiler is likely to stop you (I don't think most of them care).

An obvious workaround would be to move `main`'s functionality into a container function and call it from there, as suggested by @KlasLindbäck.

i.e.

```
int my_application(int argc, char const * argv[]) {
   // do stuff
   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char const * argv[]) {
   return my_application(argc, argv);
}
```

Another "hack" that probably only works because compilers let you call `main` anyway (As also pointed out by @KlasLindbäck in the comments), would be to use function pointers. i.e.

```
int main(int argc, char const * argv[]) {
   // do stuff
}

// shouldn't compile... but hey, you never know.
int (*prt_to_main)(int, char const* argv[]) = main;

void test_run(void) {
   prt_to_main(0, NULL);
}
```

Comment: I think any compiler that is lenient enough to allow to take the address of `main` into a function pointer would also be lenient enough to allow you to call it directly. GCC is one such example.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, I totally agree. I don't think most of them do more then issue a warning anyway... not that I've tried (I can see no good coming from calling `main` in any way).

Comment: You cannot call `my_application()` with no arguments.