# Rerunning my main method

Tags: c++, terminal, program-entry-point

I just finished an image editor that is run through terminal console commands. After an image is edited, I'm trying to get the entire program (via a main() method) to run again but I'm a bit confused on how to do so.
Here's the method I tried using to rerun the code.

```
void rerun()
{
    cout << "Would you like to alter another image? (Y/N) ";
    string answer;
    getline(cin, answer);
    while (answer != "Y" || answer != "N")

        if (answer == "N") {
            return;
        }
    if (answer == "Y") {
        main();
    }
}
```

This isn't giving me anything. What do I need to fix?

Comment: You'd probably have better luck using a loop inside `main`.

Comment: C++ standard forbids calling main from your code.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: It is undefined behavior to call `main()`. Use a loop instead or move the code you have in `main()` to a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call main() itself in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532912/call-main-itself-in-c)

Comment: It's most likely that `std::getline` returns an empty string. Perhaps there was another call to read something else before that line using `std::cin >> someVariable;` syntax.

Comment: I just ran the code through an online c++ code formatter. I have done this a few hundred times under the c++ tag to fix badly formatted code.

Comment: @abelenky Not sure about that. C++ standard 3.6.1: `The function
main shall not be used within a program.` Where exactly it says that calling main is an undefined behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ standard prohibits the direct invocation of `main()`, like you're attempting to do:

> 3.6 Start and termination
>
> ...
>
> 3 - The function main shall not be used within a program.

`main()` can only be invoked from your environment, by your operating system. You cannot invoke it directly.

Therefore, you need to restructure the logic of your program, so that it has the effect of rerunning your entire program, when needed. For example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret;

    do
    {
        ret = your_real_main(argc, argv);
    } while (ret == -1);

    return ret;
}
```

Whatever you have in your current `main()`, rename it as `you_real_main()` (and declare it accordingly), and if `your_real_main()` returns -1, it will be reexecuted, as if it was invoked again. All other return values get returned from `main()` itself, and carry whatever implication they do, for your C++ implementation.

Feel free to use any special return value from `your_real_main()`, instead of -1, for this behavior.

Of course, you are responsible for doing whatever is necessary to make this work correctly. Such as cleaning up all the resources you allocated, so by the time `your_real_main()` returns, everything that's been allocated has been freed, and the state of your application is identical to what it was when it was started (all dynamically-allocated memory has been released, all files have been closed, etc...).

With some careful planning, it is also possible to implement the same result by using a carefully-thrown exception, rather than a special return value. Then there may be operating system-specific means of accomplishing the same goals, such as `exec()` on Linux, also...

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for. Thanks man! It's working perfectly.