# How to immediately stop/end the program?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, c++17

The user is asked if s/he wants to return to main menu, if the user inputs n/N it only proceeds to the next solution when it should immediately end the program. Shown below is the code I used for the program. Please help me to make solution on how to end the program immediately when No is chosen as his/her choice. Thank you so much!

```
void number()

int b=0;
int groupChoice=0;
float ave[groupChoice];
int trials[groupChoice];
float result,sumRes,dAve;
int sumTry=0;
char choice;

cout << "\nNUMBER OF TRIALS" << endl;
cout << "\nHow many groups? ";
cin >> groupChoice;
for (int j=0;j<groupChoice;j++)
{
    cout << "Average distance for group " << j+1 << ": ";
    cin >> ave[j];
    cout << "No. of trials for group " << j+1 << ": ";
    cin >> trials[j];
}
cout << "\nGroups\t\tAve. Distance(x)\tNo. of trials(w)\tx(w)" << endl;
for (int i=0;i<groupChoice;i++)
{
    result=ave[i]*trials[i];
    cout << "Group " << i + 1 << "\t\t" << ave[i] << "\t\t\t" << trials[i] << "\t\t\t" << result << endl;
    sumTry=sumTry+trials[i];
    sumRes+=result;
}
cout << "\t\t\t\t\tSum = " << sumTry << "\t\tSum = " << sumRes << endl;
dAve = sumRes / sumTry;
cout << "Distance Average is " << dAve << endl << endl;
b=0;
while(b==0)
{
    cout << "Would you like to return to main menu? [Y or N]: ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice=='Y'||choice=='y')
    {
        b++;
        system("cls");
        a=0;
        main();
    }
    else if (choice=='N'||choice=='n')
    {
        b++;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not allowed to call `main` function in C++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532912/call-main-itself-in-c

Comment: Take a look at exit. It's in stdlib.

Answer (score 1):

You can terminate your program with

```
void std::exit( int exit_code );
```

eg

```
std::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit

Comment: Beginners would do well to think about the structure of their program so as to let it just return normally from `main`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options

use

`std::exit(<exit_code>);` or

`std::_Exit(<exit_code>);`

more info: 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/_Exit

Comment: It is not a good idea to use the latter, because it will not call destructors.