# C++ rerun program

Tags: c++

I am trying to get this portion of my C++ program to work so that the program reruns itself when 'y' is entered. When 'n' is entered, "Press any key to continue" needs to pop up.

What I have tried:

```
int main() {

    char again; 

       if (again == 'y'){
    // Asks user if they want to play again
       cout << "Would you like to play again? (y/n):";
       cin >> again;
    } else if (again == 'n'){
      cout << "Press any key to continue." << endl;
      cin.ignore(1);
```

Output should look like this when 'n' is entered:
Would you like to play again? n 
Press any key to continue . . .

output for 'y' should restart entire program

Answer (score 1):

Just can use a `do-while` loop:

```cpp
int main() {

    char again; 
    do{

        //code for the game goes here

        // Asks user if they want to play again
        cout << "Would you like to play again? (y/n):";
        cin >> again;
    }while(again=='y');
    cout << "Press any key to continue." << endl;
    cin.ignore(1);
}
```

This runs the game code over and over again until `again` is not `'y'`.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you were planning to do this: You are [not allowed to call `main` yourself in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532912/call-main-itself-in-c).

However, that does not stop you from putting everything you have in `main` into a function and call that inside a loop:

```
void my_program();

int main() {
     char again; 
     do { 
         my_program();

         // Asks user if they want to play again
         cout << "Would you like to play again? (y/n):";
         cin >> again;
     } while (again == 'y');
}
```

PS: One problem in your code is that you are using the value of `again` uninitialized.