# How do I make this function tail recursive?

Tags: c++11, recursion, tail-recursion

I am trying to make this function tail recursive so that I can use it to process a large number of events without getting a stack overflow. I made sure to put the recursive call at the last line of the function, but it still floods the call stack with recursive calls.

Is there anything else I need to do to make it tail recursive, or does my compiler just not know how to optimize it?

Should I abandon this function and use a loop instead?

```
template <class Csi>
void GetEvents(EventHandle handle, vector<int> desiredCodes, vector<EventHandle> &events, Csi &csi)
{
    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE)
    {
        return;
    }

    int code = csi.GetEventCode(handle);
    bool codeSatisfiesSearch = (find(desiredCodes.begin(), desiredCodes.end(), code) != desiredCodes.end());
    if (codeSatisfiesSearch)
    {
        events.push_back(handle);

        handle = csi.FindNextEventEx(handle, &desiredCodes[0], 0, desiredCodes.size());
    }
    else
    {
        handle = csi.FindNextEventEx(handle, &desiredCodes[0], 0, desiredCodes.size());
    }
    return GetEvents(handle, desiredCodes, events, csi);
}
```

Comment: Tail recursion is an optional optimization as far as I know. This looks like a main loop being implemented using recursion which, critically, will blow the stack if the optimization isn't applied. So, if this is the case, don't try to use recursion for this and write your loop by hand yourself. Otherwise, someone else might try to compile your code on a platform that doesn't perform tail recursion and it won't work for them. This assumes you can get the optimization to trigger in the first place.

Comment: Try passing `desiredCodes` by const reference.

Comment: Why not just use a loop?  You should be able to wrap the logic in a loop like `while(handle != INVALID_HANDLE) { int code = csi.GetEventCode(handle); ... }`

Comment: Why do you want to use tail recursion instead of a (more obvious) loop?

Comment: This is a question about optimizations. It's important to identify exactly which compiler you are using, what version and what build flags are being used. The answer can vary wildly from build configuration to build configuration.

Answer (score 7):

Taking this question on it's face value.

In the current form, the code is not suitable for TCO, due to the fact that `vector<int> desiredCodes` is passed by value. It requires caller to destruct the local vector after recursive call, so tail-call optimization is not an option.

When I changed the code to pass the vector by const reference, I noticed that  latest version of `clang` did optimize the tail call: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qM7QVv

However, `gcc` still did not: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/u7yIvR. I noticed that it is `push_back` which prevents gcc from optimizing - when commented out, recursive call is eliminated.

I was able to get gcc 9.2 to optimize the recursive call when replacing `events.push_back(handle)` with

```
events.resize(events.size() + 1);
events[events.size()  - 1] = handle;
```

All this goes to show that TCO in C++ is not something to rely on, as it is extremely fragile and depends on unpredictable factors. It's a nice bonus you might get occasionally, but not something you can build your design on.

If TCO interests you (as it interests me, for example) you will have better luck with more predictable languages like C, or, even better, with functional-style bunch.

Comment: See as well the discussion in this posting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693683/tail-recursion-in-c

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am very interested in recursion and I wanted to see if I could use it to solve this problem, but I am starting to see its limits and disadvantages. I will use a loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

Modern compilers can perform this optimization if you turn it on with a compiler flag.  I modified your code to the following, in order to get it [to compile on godbolt.org:](https://godbolt.org/z/2LMQ9h)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <vector>

class EventHandle {
  public:
    constexpr EventHandle() : dummy(~0U) {}
    constexpr auto operator==(const EventHandle& x) const
    {
       return dummy == x.dummy;
    }

  private:
    unsigned dummy;
};

constexpr EventHandle INVALID_HANDLE = EventHandle();

class Csi {
  public:
    int GetEventCode(EventHandle) const;
    EventHandle FindNextEventEx( EventHandle, const int*, int, size_t ) const;
};

void GetEvents(EventHandle handle, const std::vector<int>& desiredCodes, std::vector<EventHandle>& events, Csi &csi)
{
    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE)
    {
        return;
    }

    int code = csi.GetEventCode(handle);
    bool codeSatisfiesSearch = (std::find(desiredCodes.begin(), desiredCodes.end(), code) != desiredCodes.end());
    if (codeSatisfiesSearch)
    {
        events.push_back(handle);

        handle = csi.FindNextEventEx(handle, &desiredCodes[0], 0, desiredCodes.size());
    }
    else
    {
        handle = csi.FindNextEventEx(handle, &desiredCodes[0], 0, desiredCodes.size());
    }
    return GetEvents(handle, desiredCodes, events, csi);
}
```

I made only two significant changes. I provided stub `class` definitions for `EventHandle` and `Csi`, so that the compiler would generate code at all.  I also changed `desiredCodes` and `events` to reference parameters, so that the compiler would not make copies.  (This changes the semantics: the function now alters the original `events` object.  You might wish to declare it as `std::vector<EventHandle>&& events` to make it more explicit that you clobber the input parameter.)  [I also added `std::` to STL types and algorithms.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

MSVC 19.22 x64 optimizes this to tail-recursion if you give it the `/Ox` flag.  GCC 9.2 x86_64 requires `-O2` or higher.  Clang 8.0.0 and ICC 19.0.1 both require `-O` or higher.  For example, with `-O`, line 213 of the ICC code listing optimizes to a `jmp`.

```
jmp GetEvents(EventHandle, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&, std::vector<EventHandle, std::allocator<EventHandle> >&, Csi&) #44.12
```

Without optimization flags, line 1724 performs a recursive non-tail call.

```
call GetEvents(EventHandle, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&, std::vector<EventHandle, std::allocator<EventHandle> >&, Csi&) #44.12
```