# define function template alias by using

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I define a function template alias:

```
template <typename T>
using Cb = typename std::add_pointer<void(bool, T)>::type;
```

but got this error :

> error: cannot convert 'Log::operator()(Read&) [with T = int]::' to 'Cb' {aka 'void (*)(bool, int)'} in assignment

```
template <typename T>
class Log : public Sink<T> {
public:
    void
    operator()(Read<T> &read) {
        if (!more_) {
            // error !!!
            more_ = std::function<Cb<T>>([&](bool done, T val) {
                if (!done) {
                    cout << val << endl;
                    this->operator()(read);
                }
            });
        }
        read(false, more_);
    }

private:
    Cb<T> more_ = nullptr;
};
```

main function:

```
int main() {

    Log<int> logInt;

    return 0;
}
```

who to resolve this syntax error?

[code example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8d76f665ea07898)

Comment: Lambda with captures cannot be casted to pointer to function. It could only work with stateless lambdas. Put the link with real  code, now it doesn't match what you posted in question.

Comment: but, how to correct it, can you help me? this is the real code example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8d76f665ea07898

Comment: Why not just define `Cb` as:  `template <typename T> using Cb = std::function<void(bool,T)>;` ?

Comment: Fully agree with rafix07. Here is a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/544045333da0315c)

Comment: Thanks rafix07 and StefanKssmr, the live example is right

Comment: another question, how to make this line `this->operator()(read);`  tail recursion optimization enabled @StefanKssmr in the [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77d1df531d3f357f)

Comment: @langyu maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2693702/8359552) helps to restructure your `void Log<T>::operator()(Read<T> &read)`. To enable tail recursion optimisation `this->operator()(read)` should be the last statement in your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is that

`std::function<Cb<T>>` resolve to `std::function<void (*)(bool, int)>` whereas you want

`std::function<void (bool, int)>`.

So you might change your alias to

```
template <typename T>
using Cb = void(bool, T);
```