# Factorial function in C++ with Tail Recursion

Tags: c++, c, recursion, tail-recursion

I was wondering what a tail recursive factorial function would look like. In one of my lectures they said it should be pretty easy to implement, but I cant imagine how to implement it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion

Comment: `int fac(int n, int acc=1){return n?fac(n-1, acc*n):acc;}`

Answer (score 0):

Just a basic `C` snippet:

```
unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n){
    if(n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Here, `factorial()` function is calling `factorial()` function again i.e. `recursion`.

Comment: I know GCC does tail recursion but the standard doesn't guarantee tail recursion, does it?

Comment: This isn't a tail recursive factorial function, because it modifies the returned value from the recursive call. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2693719/5231607) to one of the marked duplicates for an example of a tail recursive factorial function.