# Ensuring tail-call optimization in C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, tail-call-optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which, if any, C++ compilers do tail-recursion optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125/which-if-any-c-compilers-do-tail-recursion-optimization)

I'm writing a small runtime for a Lisp-like language for educational purposes, but I'd like to make sure the C code is tail-call optimized, since I'm depending on it in my language. Are there any compilers which guarantee tail-call recursion being optimized? If so, is there documentation of what rules there are for causing the recursion to be optimized?

Obiviously, gcc or clang would be nice, but I need to ensure that code is being properly optimized, since it depends on it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125/which-if-any-c-compilers-do-tail-recursion-optimization

Comment: I don't understand.  Is the output of your runtime C code?  If so, can't you just write the code that you emit in a tail-optimized fashion?

Comment: @slugonamission: Will that work for C?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think he was asking if there was a way to ensure your compiler performed tail-call optimisation. Also, I would assume so, since tail-call optimisation is pretty agnostic on the differences between C and C++...

Comment: Also, the top replies in that topic are written in C ;)