# Linked list delete

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T>
List<T>::~List()
{
    while(head->next !=NULL){
        delete head;
        head = head->next;
    }
    head = NULL;
}
```

I want to delete all the nodes in the linked list, but I don' t know why the code fail.

Comment: `delete head; head = head->next;` is bad. You may not access `head` after `delete head;`.

Comment: Note, that VS (in debug mode) fills deleted memory with test bit patterns to uncover [UB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939). At this point, chances are high that your code crashs. (This is actually the intention.)

Comment: A similar question (and my answer): [SO: Destructing a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45389774/7478597)

Comment: You are also not deleting the last element of the linked list, which causes a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails probably because it invokes *undefined behaviour*.

```
delete head;
head = head->next;
```

You cannot read the memory located where `head` points *after* having `delete`d `head`.

You should make a copy of `head->next` to reuse it:

```
const auto next = head->next;
delete head;
head = next;
```

Comment: @peter auto is a C++11 addition to let the compiler infer (guess) the type of the defined variable. If you wish not use it, replace `auto` with the type of `head->next` (I cannot know it from your question).

Comment: while(head->next!=NULL){
          Node*next = head->next;
          delete head;
               head = next;
         }
         head = NULL; is it correct now?

Comment: @peter yes. `head` is a `Node *`, and so is `Node::next`?

Comment: That fixes the invalid memory access, but leaves the issue with the leaking memory of the last element.

Comment: @PedramAzad the memory leak is indeed good to mention, and I forgot about it. You might write an answer, I'll be the first one to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the following solution. No invalid memory access, no memory leak, and it automatically assigns NULL to `head` before leaving the loop:

```
template<typename T>
List<T>::~List()
{
    while (head)
    {
        Node<T> *next = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = next;
    }
}
```

Please note that I made a guess with the node type and you have to replace it by whatever is present in your code.

Comment: as promised ;) (first)

Answer (score 0):

This can help you in deleting every node of linked list.

```
   List<T> *current = head;
   while (current != NULL) 
   {
       next = current->next;
       delete current;
       current = next;
   }
```

Comment: What make you think the type of `head` and `head->next` is `List<T>`?

Comment: what is next can I just use head but not current?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what type the head variable is. If it is the class, you can even use "recursive" deleting in "head" (I mean node) destructor. Something similar to:

```
Node::~Node(){
    if(this->next != nullptr)
        delete this->next;
    delete this->content;
}
```

If the node is internal struct, you need temporary pointer to next node as mentioned above:

```
template<typename T>
List<T>::~List()
{
    struct nodeType *temp;
    while(head != nullptr){
        temp = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = temp;
    }
}
```

In this case, you don't need to explicitly set head to null, since it is done by the logic of while loop.

In your loop (in question) you don't remove *head node, I don't know if it is expected behavior.

Ad. comment above (I can't put it directly):
while(head->next!=NULL){ Node*next = head->next; delete head; head = next; } head = NULL;
is wrong. It doesn't delete last node on the list (especially if the list has only one object, it won't be deleted).