# Auxiliary space complexity of this solution

Tags: linked-list, tail-recursion, space-complexity

This is a tail-recursive solution for reversing a singly linked list. What is the auxiliary space occupied by this solution?

```
void reverseUtil(Node* curr, Node* prev, Node** head)
{
    if (curr->next==NULL) {
        *head = curr;
        curr->next = prev;
        return;
    }
    Node* next = curr->next;
    curr->next = prev;
    reverseUtil(next, curr, head);
}

void reverse(Node** head)
{
    if (head==NULL)
        return;
    reverseUtil(*head, NULL, head);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your code should check that `*head` is not NULL before making the initial call to `reverseUtil`, so add this condition here:

```
if (head==NULL || *head==NULL)
    return;
```

This is indeed a case of tail recursion. [All current mainstream C compilers perform tail call optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34129/5459839) when the relevant option is set, and then the tail recursive calls are actually not increasing the stack space usage.

So provided that the compiler is instructed to perform this optimisation, the auxiliary space usage is *O(1)*.

After the optimisation, the execution and space usage will be quite similar to what this iterative code would do:

```
void reverse(Node** head)
{
    if (head==NULL || *head==NULL)
        return;
    Node* curr = *head;
    Node* prev = NULL;
    while (true) {
        if (curr->next==NULL) {
            *head = curr;
            curr->next = prev;
            return;
        }
        Node* next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
}
```